# ‘string’ does not name a type error" in eclipse cdt

Tags: c++, std, eclipse-cdt, stdstring, codan

I added a new source folder to my code and create a new class with below header and cpp file

```
#ifndef ENVIRONMENT_H_
#define ENVIRONMENT_H_

#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

namespace daemonWorld {

class Environment {
    const string objName;
public:
    Environment(const string & name){
        this->objName = name;

    }
    virtual ~Environment();
};

} /* namespace daemonWorld */

#endif /* TEMP_ENVIRONMENT_H_ */
```

CPP file

```
#include "Environment.h"


namespace daemonWorld {


Environment::~Environment() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

} /* namespace daemonWorld */
```

I am getting an error that string is not a type in constructor and the member variable Obj 
and I am getting Codan error in cpp file Member declaration not found
for constructor. 
I have many times cleaned the project, rebuild the index and rebuild the project but it doesn't work. Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>
```

should be

```
#include <string>
```

`string.h` is the C string header. `string` is the C++ string header.

Furthermore, all standard C++ headers omit the `.h`. Even the C headers, when included from C++ code should be prefixed with `c` in addition to omitting the `.h`. E.g. `cstring` would be the correct header to include to get the C string header in C++.

Comment: I accepted your answer however I defined the <string.h> in other files without problem. I think eclipse cdt had a problem with refreshing the indexes some how. After I add a new source folder. It has happened before as well.

Comment: @Govan Yes your compiler might allow including `some_std_header.h` but you can't rely on that behavior. As far as the Standard is concerned, those headers don't exist. Relying on implementation-defined behavior is generally bad.